# PHPUnit assertTrue if regex text found?

Tags: php, phpunit, assert

I'm using PHPUnit and trying to check if text exists on a page. The assertRegExp works but using the if statement I get the error `Failed asserting that null is true.`

I understand that $test is returning null, but I don't know how to have it return 1 or 0 or true/false if the text exists? Any help's appreciated thanks.

```
        $element = $this->byCssSelector('body')->text();
        $test = $this->assertRegExp('/find this text/i',$element);

        if($this->assertTrue($test)){
            echo 'text found';
        }
        else{
            echo 'not found';
        }
```

Comment: An assertSomething() does not belong into an if statement. It is a species that exists in isolation. So at least for me it's not clear what you do here. Normally there is also no output involved within unit-tests. May I ask why you want/need that to do?

Comment: @hakre if the text exists on the page I need to start running different functions. How can I write a conditional for this?

Comment: Why would you want to? This is unit-testing and works pretty well without conditionals.

Comment: Also having more than one assertion per test is usually not a good sign.

Comment: @Anagio: Don't use `$this->assertSomething()` if it's not an assertion you want to test for. Also you should not do many decisions in your test-code (just to keep it simple), however, if you still want to do, just do it. Nobody stops you, it's just that such a decision then is just not an assertion so you're just using the wrong tool for the job. Regular expressions in PHP are here: http://php.net/preg_match and http://php.net/pcre

Answer (score 27):

`assertRegExp()` will return nothing. If the assertion fails - meaning the text was not found - then the following code won't get executed:

```
 $this->assertRegExp('/find this text/i',$element);
 // following code will not get executed if the text was not found
 // and the test will get marked as "failed"
```

Comment: This method is deprecated since PHPUnit v9.0. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66692244/771469) for the newest version!

Answer (score 12):

Use this method in **newer** phpunit versions:

```php
$this->assertMatchesRegularExpression('/PATTERN/', $yourString);
```

Answer (score 5):

PHPUnit is not designed to return value from assertions. Assertions by definition are meant to break the flow when they fail.

If you need to do something like this, why do you use PHPUnit at all? Use `preg_match`:

```
 $test = preg_match('/find this text/i', $element);

 if($test) {
        echo 'text found';
 }
 else {
        echo 'text not found';
 }
```

Comment: PHPUnit IS designed to support such operations. Take a look at @hek2mgl answer.

Comment: This depends on what you mean by _such operations_. I meant that PHPUnit is not designed to return value from assertions. Assertions by definition are meant to break the flow when they fail. If you want to use result of regexp match in an `if` statement, then `preg_match` is the way to go.

Comment: I got you now. It seemed to me you were trying to say that "such operations" like `assertRegExp`.